# Calculating Range from Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a more suitable way to retrieve a range (difference between highest and lowest number) from this Binary Search Tree? I've tried returning the difference between the max & min value in the range function but nothing is working.

Here's my code:

```py
# %load bst.py


class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None
        # self.parent = None


class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None  # the root of the tree

    def insert(self, new_node):
        if self.root is None:  # is the tree empty?
            self.root = new_node  # if yes, new node becomes the root
            return
        self.insertNode(self.root, new_node)

    def insertNode(self, root, new_node):
        if new_node.data > root.data:
            if root.right_child is not None:  # does right child exist?
                self.insertNode(root.right_child, new_node)
            else:
                root.right_child = new_node  # new node becomes right child
                return
        else:  # case where new_node.data <= root.data
            if root.left_child is not None:  # does left child exist?
                self.insertNode(root.left_child, new_node)
            else:  # left child does not exist
                root.left_child = new_node

    # assignment starts here
    def postOrder(self, node):
        if node.left_child is not None:  # does the left child exist?
            self.postOrder(node.left_child)
        if node.right_child is not None:  # checking if right child exists
            self.postOrder(node.right_child)
        print(node.data)  # visit the node

    # finding maxmum of the array
    def findMax(self, node):
        if node.right_child is not None:  # does the right child exist?
            return self.findMax(node.right_child)
        print(node.data)  # visit the node

    # finding minmum of the array
    def findMin(self, node):
        if node.left_child is not None:  # check if left child exist
            return self.findMin(node.left_child)
        print(node.data)  # visit the node

    # finding range
    def range(numbers=[8, 87]):
        import statistics

        statistics.range
        return max(numbers) - min(numbers)


my_bst = BST()
l = [31, 67, 26, 29, 50, 15, 58, 8, 49, 87, 20]
for n in l:
    n1 = Node(n)
    my_bst.insert(n1)

print('maxmum of the array is')
my_bst.findMax(my_bst.root)
print('minmum of the array is')
my_bst.findMin(my_bst.root)
print('postOrdering the array follows')
my_bst.postOrder(my_bst.root)
print('range is')
my_bst.range(my_bst.root)
```

I've attempted but I keep getting the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 76, in <module>
    my_bst.range(my_bst.root)
TypeError: range() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given`
```

Comment: Show your code and error as properly formatted text in the question. And try to show the tree.

Comment: I have added the code sample.

Comment: "range" misses the "self" parameter or a `@staticmethod` decorator

Comment: not sure what you mean. could you explain with regard to my code?

Answer (score 1):

The `range` fonction should be a **method**, so you need to define the *self* parameter as the first argument of the function, like this:

```py
class BST:

    [...]

    # finding range
    def range(self, numbers=[8, 87]):
        import statistics

        statistics.range
        return max(numbers) - min(numbers)
```

Notice that this is not a good practice to have a mutable parameter because it is not in the local scope of the function. You can fix this as bellow:

```py
    def range(self, numbers=None):
        if numbers is None:
            numbers = [8, 87]
        import statistics

        statistics.range
        return max(numbers) - min(numbers)
```

In short, you can also write:

```py
    # finding range
    def range(self, numbers=None):
        numbers = numbers or [8, 87]
        import statistics

        statistics.range
        return max(numbers) - min(numbers)
```

It is better to import `statistics` globally, like this:

```py
import statistics


class BST:

    [...]

    # finding range
    def range(self, numbers=None):
        numbers = numbers or [8, 87]

        statistics.range
        return max(numbers) - min(numbers)
```

Notice that the `statistics.range` function is not called because you forget the parenthesis (and the parameters). So this is dead code.

In your main program, you try to call `my_bst.range()` with a `my_bst.root` which is a `Node` instance. So, you'll have a error when calculating `max/min` on a `Node`:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 75, in <module>
    my_bst.range(my_bst.root)
  File "...", line 59, in range
    return max(numbers) - min(numbers)
TypeError: 'Node' object is not iterable
```

You need to develop your algorithm by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You design doesn't make much sense.  The reason you would have a separate `BST` class is so that you can write methods over trees that don't rely on recursion.  If you're going to rely on recursion, then it makes more sense to just have a `Node` class, because every node is itself a binary tree.

Here's how I would rewrite the `findMin`, `findMax` and `range` methods of `BST`

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
    def insert(self, value):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(value) 
        else:
            curr_node = self.root
            while True:
                if value < curr_node.data:
                    if curr_node.left is None:
                        curr_node.left = Node(value)
                        return
                    else:
                        curr_node = curr_node.left
                elif value > curr_node.data:
                    if curr_node.right is None:
                        curr_node.right = Node(value)
                        return
                    else:
                        curr_node = curr_node.right
                else:
                    return
    def min(self):
        if self.root is None:
            raise TypeError("Empty Tree")
        curr_node = self.root
        while curr_node.left is not None:
            curr_node = curr_node.left
        return curr_node.data
    def max(self):
        if self.root is None:
            raise TypeError("Empty Tree")
        curr_node = self.root
        while curr_node.right is not None:
            curr_node = curr_node.right
        return curr_node.data
    def range(self):
        return self.max() - self.min()


my_bst = BST()
l = [31, 67, 26, 29, 50, 15, 58, 8, 49, 87, 20]
for v in l:
    my_bst.insert(v)
 print(my_bst.range())  # 79
```